# JavaScript code optimization with ES6 standards

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, eslint

I am not really strong with ES6, therefore looking forward to getting a small hand :c. How can I optimize this code for a better visual appearance? I have tried the following solution, however, I am sure that I can use array `Array.prototype` methods here like `.map()` or alike. The idea here is to ensure that the list of const will never be `undefined` and in case they are – use the right hand side case:

```js
function getLeadingComments(context) {
    const contextOptions = context?.options[0];

    const description = contextOptions?.description || 'React based Progressive Web App';
    const author = contextOptions?.author || '';
    const license = contextOptions?.license || 'OSL-3.0';
    const packageName = contextOptions?.package || 'Powered by My Project';

    return `/**
 * ${description}
 *
 * Copyright © ${author}. All rights reserved.
 * See LICENSE for license details.
 *
 * @license ${license}
 * @package ${packageName}
 */
`;
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator

Comment: Optional chaining is not part of ES6. It was introduced in ES2020.

Comment: you could consider use destructuring assignment instead with a default parameter: https://jsfiddle.net/q0gr9uxy/1/

Comment: @NickParsons you are the superstar!

Answer (score 0):

As `Ivar` said optional chaining is introduced in [ES2020](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining) and you can use [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) that returns right hand side if left side operand is `null` or `undefined`.

```
function getLeadingComments(context) {
  const contextOptions = context?.options[0];

  const description =
    contextOptions?.description ?? "React based Progressive Web App";
  const author = contextOptions?.author ?? "";
  const license = contextOptions?.license ?? "OSL-3.0";
  const packageName = contextOptions?.package ?? "Powered by My Project";

  return `
/*
 * ${description}
 *
 * Copyright © ${author}. All rights reserved.
 * See LICENSE for license details.
 *
 * @license ${license}
 * @package ${packageName}
 */
`;
}

getLeadingComments({
  options: [
    {
      description: "Incoming Data Description",
      author: "Incoming Data Author",
      license: "Incoming Data License",
      package: "Incoming Data Package",
    },
  ],
});
```